# AppManifest Validation failed. Invalid AppPlatformVersion in WMAppmanifest.xml

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8

I recently upgraded my WP8 Silverlight Application to 8.1 Silverlight.
But now, ehwn building I always get this error message

```
AppManifest Validation failed. Invalid AppPlatformVersion in WMAppmanifest.xml  Bedtime Music
```

What went wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you change the platform target from the WMAppmanifest?

Comment: @anonshankar No, I used Visual Studios automatic upgrade

Comment: http://www.geekchamp.com/news/an-interesting-windows-phone-build-error-manifest-validation-failed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nah, I found out by myself:
In the WMAppmanifest file there is this line:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2012/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="8.0">
```

To deal with the resulting error that occurs when just setting 8.0 to 8.1 I also needed to change the year from 2012 to 2014

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2014/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="8.1">
```

Also somewehere else in the file.