# Package acceptance validation error: WMAppManifest.xml wasn’t found

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I built my windows8.1 silverlight app with vs2015.

while submitting to store its complain as "Package acceptance validation error: WMAppManifest.xml wasn’t found" tough it exists.
Local windows app certification kit complaining that there is an error in reading this file.

also looked into below post, MY wmappmanifest schema looks correct

[AppManifest Validation failed. Invalid AppPlatformVersion in WMAppmanifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226814/appmanifest-validation-failed-invalid-appplatformversion-in-wmappmanifest-xml)

Could you please help me in figuring out the issue here? you help is highly appricated.

Comment: Can you show your WMAppManifest.xml file?

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. here is the manifest file link. http://1drv.ms/1mCe1nf

Comment: My silly mistake. After editing xap file creating folder inside folder while zipping. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My silly mistake. After editing xap file, while creating zip file creating folder inside folder. It is fixed now.